# Set default value on entity list in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I defined a form entity list:

```
->add('businessTime', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeDemoBundle:BusinessTimes',
    'property' => 'name',
    'required' => true
);
```

With this the list is displayed but with blank option as default. I would like to display a selected option from the entity by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the data property for that

```
 ->add('businessTime', 'entity',   array(
    'class' => 'AcmeDemoBundle:BusinessTimes',
    'property' => 'name',
    'data' => 1234456,
    'required' => true
     );
```

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly do I have to put as value? An entity selected object or a propery?

Comment: you could use ? operator like : 'data'=> $yourProp?$yourProp:"defaultVal"